# Getting google fonts local on wordpress and remove old fonts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, google-font-api

I am looking for a solution to move a theme default google font to my own ftp server. It's this font: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic%7CBitter:400,700%7CSource+Sans+Pro:300,300italic,400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,latin,latin. I want to remove this because of my google pagespeed score. I am using the wordpress twenty thirteen theme and I have already tried a couple of solutions, but they didn't work for this theme. I have already downloaded the files with google-webfonts-helper.

Answer (score 0):

The problem & solution likely lies with the amount of font variations that you are loading, rather than the method.

For Source Sans, you are loading many variations twice.

Try only loading the variations (weights & styles) that you actually utilize. For example, if you are using Source Sans default (not thin, bold, black, or italics) only load Source Sans Pro 400. Same goes for Bitter. Ensure that you remove the second instance of Source Sans Pro also.

After removing unused & unnecessary fonts, check page speed again.

Comment: The problem is that I can't find where I can delete those fonts. I have tried in functions.php and custom-header.php, but he keeps loading the same url.

Comment: You can delete them directly from the call.  For example, change: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic%7CBitter:400,700%7CSource+Sans+Pro:300,300italic,400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,latin,latin'  to this 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400%7CBitter:400'

Comment: The problem is that I can't find the call. I want to find the call, delete it and import the offline css.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use google fonts then use @import url(' Your font's Link') in the very first of your CSS. or go to your HTLML editor and type the following code just below your head tag

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic%7CBitter:400,700%7CSource+Sans+Pro:300,300italic,400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,latin,latin')
</style>
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't find where I can delete those fonts. I have tried in functions.php and custom-header.php, but he keeps loading the same url.